# Create new dataframe based on the absence / presence of all words in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I would like to process a list of sentences into a new dataframe, the dataframe should have the maximum number of columns based on the number of unique number of words in a vocabulary.

In the dataframe each column should indicate if a word of the sentence is present in the dictionary- if true (fill in value 1) or not true (fill in value 0).

List of sentences:

```
sentence = [['I','like','fruit'],['cars','are','great'],['great','time','eating','fruit']]
```

Vocabulary that contains all unique words - total length of vocabulary = 8

```
vocab = ['I','like','fruit','cars','are','great','time','eating']
```

Finally, I would like to add the corresponding label to each sentence.

Labels:

```
labels = ['Fruit','Cars','Fruit']
```

The dataframe filled with 0 values is created like so for now:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(4), columns=np.arange(8))
new_df = new_df.fillna(0)
```

Expected Results:

```
          Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4 Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Label 

Sentence1   1      1     1     0    0     0     0    0     Fruit
Sentence2   0      0     0     1    1     1     0    0     Car  
Sentence3   0      0     1     0    0     1     1    0     Fruit
```

Comment: What issues have you had so far? how are you initializing your data frame ?

Comment: @Manakin I'm not sure how to initialize a data frame with x amount of columns that are iteratively named Word1,Word2, etc - I should probably add that to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sentences = [
    ['I','like','fruit'],
    ['cars','are','great'],
    ['great','time','eating','fruit']
]

# For each sentence, create a dictionary of <word>: 1 for each word
words_dict = [{word: 1 for word in sentence} for sentence in sentences]

# Convert to data frame, fill in the empty values and rename the columns as required
df = pd.DataFrame(words_dict).fillna(0)
df.columns = ['Word{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(len(df.columns))]
```

This is pretty naive; you'd have to investigate how efficient panda's "list of dictionaries to DataFrame" and "fill in sparse data frame" are.

Comment: This obviously doesn't create the `Label` column you have in your example because I'm not sure how you're getting that from the sentences.

Comment: Thank you - the original data frame that I use, only had two columns (one called sentences, the other called labels)! Should have made that clearer.